# Cambiar puerto Oracle 11g

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-server-2008-r2

me gustaría saber cómo cambiar el puerto de **oracle 11g** y cual ocupar, es decir, saber uno que está libre, ya que el puerto 8080 está ocupado por **sql server** y el 8081 **Mysql.**
Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Se cambia con ese comando en sqlplus o en cmd sqlplus / as sysdba:

```
exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport(8082);
```

y verificamos el cambio de puerto con:

```
select dbms_xdb.sethttpport() from dual;
```